# rss feed using C# and gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, rss

I'm trying to read an xml file from a url and print the contents to a data grid to build a simple rss feed, here is my code:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("url to an xml file");
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(reader);
gridview1.DataBind();
```

what i'm getting is an exception saying:
"Cannot add constraint to DataTable 'a' which is a child table in two nested relations."

what does that mean? what am i doing wrong???

Comment: decided to use jquery instead! problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I believe XML instances where subnodes have the same name are not fully supported. Does your XML  have any child nodes with the same name as any ancestor nodes?

Edit: this article might somewhat help you http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/dataset.aspx.
Though it is in Managed C++, the logic is the same.

Comment: as i'm a newbie i'm afraid i have to ask you to explain more, thank you

Comment: thanks for the article, but i still don't understand what exactly the problem is, and how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Check out this little guy:
[XML Inference Problem](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/167647/cannot-add-constraint-child-table-in-two-nested-relations)

The problem is that there are two elements with identically named child nodes.  It seems that this is a known issue with VS.  You could always try getting the information into XSD format or writing your own XML schema to work with the feed?

Comment: nice, now i've taken a step forward, and now i understand that there are 2 nodes in the xml that i'm getting from a url that have the exact same name, so the solution is to read the xml file that is in the specific url with XmlSchema, any idea how to read it to a DataSet afterwards?